# rake db:seed information being printed on my website

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a rails app for a Boosting site. I have gone through and made some has_many and belongs_to relationships to show a basic preview and then will show more options of "League" such as "Diamond 3 Carry" etc with pricing options. However when seed the db with some data the entire seed gets printed on my website below the columns.

[image: ???]

There is nothing in my code to make it appear on the screen like that as far as i am aware so how do i fix it?

Comment: can you please post your view of this page

Comment: I doubt you are using `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>` somewhere

Comment: I think, when you are eaching on a variable, mistakenly type the variable in <%= @example %>, just remove = from this like <% %>

Comment: answer found, was typing <%= when i was starting to reference my data instead of <% which resulted in it being printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have something like this:

```
<%= @something_object.each do |key| %>
```

remove '='  from this:

```
<% @something_object.each do |key| %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is <%= meaning "print the value of" and <% means "prepare the value of" new to rails